# Geolocation fails in Chrome/Safari, not Firefox/Opera

Tags: google-maps, google-chrome, geolocation, maps

I'm trying to run `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` through a rails app @ `localhost:3000`. The relevant code is taken from [Google's Geolocation Demo](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geolocation) and run through rails.

At present, the geolocation *occassionally* succeeds through Chrome (~10% of the time), *always* works almost immediately in opera, works ~80% of the time in Firefox and always fails immediately in Safari.

In failing browsers, only Safari returns an error in the console. Specifically,

`Access to geolocation was blocked over insecure connection to http://localhost:3000`

That makes sense for Safari, however from what I understand `localhost` is whitelisted in other browsers (including Chrome) and should function. Not to mention, it works *some* times - and always in Opera.

In the failing instances, nothing is returned to the console/inspector, and the `getCurrentPosition` method never returns anything unless I set a `timeout` argument (in which case it returns a timeout error).

Any thoughts on what could cause geolocation to work locally on some browsers consistently, others inconsistently, and others not at all? I'm completely stumped on this one - any thoughts appreciated. Code below

**geolocation.js**:

```
var map, infoWindow;
function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
        zoom: 6
    });
    infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

    // Try HTML5 geolocation.
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            var pos = {
                lat: position.coords.latitude,
                lng: position.coords.longitude
            };

            infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
            infoWindow.setContent('Location found.');
            infoWindow.open(map);
            map.setCenter(pos);
        }, function() {
            handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
        });
    } else {
        // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
        handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
    }
}

function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
    infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
    infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
        'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
        'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
    infoWindow.open(map);
}
```

**views/contact_details/new.html.slim**

```
#map
script(src="/geolocation.js")
<script async defer src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBSSvl9zJIZIXXgp7LMYKNU7-l9cwJSAiw&callback=initMap"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have also encountered this. There appears to be a bug in the latest Chrome 65 release (March 2018) which has made getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() inconsistently timeout rather than return a result. So far I have been unable to find a work around for this problem, so currently awaiting a fix from Google.

As a temporary measure I suggest passing in the 'timeout' value as the third parameter to the getCurrentPosition() call in order to at least have the function come back after a time to be handled gracefully. You can then relay information to the user via the error handler function.

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    function (position) {
        // on success this will be called.
    }, 
    function (err) {
        // on error this will be called (including timeout).
    },
    {
        timeout: 5000
    }
);
```

I have used a similar approach in an example here: [Chrome Geolocate Bug](https://absolutecommerce.co.uk/geolocation-getcurrentposition-function-broken-in-chrome-65)

There is a bug report here which looks to be relevant: [Chromium Issue 820945](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=820945&can=2&start=0&num=100&q=geolocation&colspec=ID)